# I need to be able to pad the ethernet layer of a tcp packet using Pcap.Net

Tags: c#, tcp, ethernet, pcap.net

I am using Pcap.net to try and establish a TCP client/server connection with c# code. I have a packet built and can send out a SYN, but the particular server I am trying to connect with needs extra 2 bytes of padding on the Ethernet layer. From all the Pcap.net documentation I haven't been able to find a away to add padding to that layer before I submit it to the packet builder. If anyone has any information on how I might achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

The two wireshark screen grabs illustrate the packet that gets accepted by the server (with padding), and the one that doesn't(no padding) respectively[image: Padding]
[image: No Padding]

Answer (score 0):

The padding is added implicitly when you send the packet over the wire.